# Choice of Point From Interior of Square

Tags: statistics, self-learning

I'm working on assigning a probability to this problem:

> The choice of a point from the interior of a square with opposite vertices $(-1, 1)$ and $(1,1)$ where the event C occurs if the sum of the coordinates of the point is less than $\frac{1}{2}$.

I think this would be:
$\int^{1}_{-1}Pr(X=x) * (\int^{\frac{1}{2} - x}_{-1}Pr((Y = y)|(X = x))$ $dy)$ $dx$

Does this look roughly right?  If so, how would I go about assigning a numerical value to this integral?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you drawn a picture? Also, you really need to change notation, for $Pr(x = x)$ is surely $1$ as written. And you should be using a pdf rather than the probability, since the probability that $x$ is any particular value turns out to be zero (at least for the uniform distribution).

Comment: Thank you - I've edited my notation (it should have been $Pr(X = x)$).  How would I go about finding the pdf for this problem?

Comment: Is the point picked uniformly randomly? Then $X$ is a uniform random variable on the interval $[-1, 1]$; the pdf for a uniform random variable on an interval is something you should know about (or look up) before trying to do a problem like this one. Yeah, I'm suggestion you look up a definition. Once you've done that 5 or 6 times, you'll actually know it. Teach a man to fish... (and he'll sit in a boat and drink beer all day.)

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand this now.  My understanding is that the probability is $\int^1_{-1}{Pr(Y \leq 1 - x)Pr(X \leq x)} = \int^1_{-1}{\frac{2-x}{2} * \frac{x+1}{2}} = \frac{5}{6}$.  Is this roughly correct?

Comment: Well... it's within 1 of the correct answer. :) I haven't actually worked out the answer; I'm just here to give guidance, not to act as an oracle for guesses. Why don't you edit your question to explain WHY you think that's the correct expression for the probability, giving enough detail that you, an hour ago, would have understood it, and then also explain why you think that the formulas on the right express the probabilities on the left. Then someone can help guide you to any errors you might have made. You might also want to answer my first question: "Have you drawn a picture?".

Comment: Thanks, you're absolutely right.  I drew a picture before, but it was the wrong picture.  Re-thinking it graphically helped a lot.